# Open a website in crosswalk webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

I'm building app with newest versions of cordova and crosswalk. When i launch the app, i want to open mywebsite in crosswalk webview instead of default browser or chrome.
   I'm trying to use:

1. `window.location.href="http://www.webpage.com"`
2. `window.open('http://webpage.com', '_self');`

But they did not work. If i use them, the app asks me where i want to open my site in chrome or in default browser. I tried to use:

1. `navigator.app.loadUrl("http://google.com", {openExternal : true});`

But i've got a white screen in app.
   I don't want to use InAppBrowser, cuz it opens website in default webview, i wanna open website exactly in Crosswalk webview. Can someone help me to open website in crosswalk webview?

Comment: Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this post?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9573

They suggest to use:

```
//config.xml
<allow-navigation href="http://cordova.apache.org/*" />

//code
window.open('http://cordova.apache.org/', '_self');
```