# Crosswalk InAppBrowser in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, crosswalk

I am struggling with opening the website inside the Cordova app using the Crosswalk engine. The default InAppBrowser is rendering the page inproperly, because it uses native WebView(which works bad on older phones like Android 4.3). I am trying to use the `cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview` and while it seems to render the cordova view with Crosswalk(the `navigator.userAgent` says so), when I call either `window.open` or `cordova.InAppBrowser`(after installing `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`) it uses the native WebView.

Is there something special I have to do to make it render that way ? I also tried this package [github](https://github.com/Shoety/cordova-plugin-inappbrowserxwalk), but it seems to not be able to allow executing scripts in the inner browser and I need some sort of communication between the Cordova app and the browser page. Maybe there is some other way for making this communication work(the intention is to be able to show barcode scanner when clicking on the button).

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue ? Big thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
//config.xml
<allow-navigation href="http://cordova.apache.org/*" />

//code
window.open('http://cordova.apache.org/', '_self');
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9573

[Open a website in crosswalk webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694673/open-a-website-in-crosswalk-webview)